# Getting the file metadata information when it adding (creating) or modifying in a specific folder

Tags: java, c#, file

I want to get the file information when a file is added or modified in a specific folder. I tried using a File Watcher in C# but it is not working properly. If there another way to do it please let me know. I am looking to write this in either C# or Java. This is my code.

```
private void fswBarCode_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RequestsManager objRequestsManager = new RequestsManager();
        Requests objRequests = new Requests();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)objRequestsManager.GetPendingRequests();
        List<Requests> lstRequest = new List<Requests>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            objRequests = new Requests();
            objRequests.RecipeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["intRecipeID"]);
            objRequests.ChemicalReqID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["intCRHeaderID"]);
            lstRequest.Add(objRequests);

        }

        if (e.ChangeType == System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            string fileName = file.Name;

            char[] ch = { '.' };
            string strrecipeID = fileName.Split(ch)[0];
            int intRecipeID = Convert.ToInt32(strrecipeID);

            if (lstRequest.Count() != 0)
            {
                lstRequest = (from lst in lstRequest
                              where lst.RecipeID.Equals(intRecipeID)
                              select lst).ToList();
                if (lstRequest.Count() != 0)
                {
                    bool blIsSuccess = objRequestsManager.SaveChemicalRequisitions(lstRequest);
                    if (blIsSuccess == true)
                    {
                        Logger.LoggIssueItems(strrecipeID);
                        List<Requests> lstRequest1 = (List<Requests>)PendingRequests();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Logger.LoggError(ex, "fswBarCode_Changed");

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and we might help you with that. Stackoverflow is not here to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by using Java nio api, like below

> The java.nio.file package and its related package,
>   java.nio.file.attribute, provide comprehensive support for file I/O
>   and for accessing the default file system

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```